Oled ssd1309 Stm32 Cube Ide not correct

I am trying to use my SSD1309 display with STM32 Cube IDE (I cannot use Arduino as it is work-related). However, with each function using the u8g2 library, my screen displays artifacts as shown in the image. The same issue occurs with other libraries. I believe it is related to my initialization, but I'm not sure. As you can see on the drawn line, it seems that the first pixels of each page are correct (the first 8 correct ones), but the rest aren't. My STM32 is a STM32G0 type.
uint8_t u8x8_gpio_and_delay_stm32(u8x8_t *u8x8, uint8_t msg, uint8_t arg_int, void *arg_ptr)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_AND_DELAY_INIT:
        /* Insert codes for initialization */
        HAL_Delay(1);
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_NANO:                    
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < arg_int; ++i)
            ;
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_DELAY_MILLI:
        /* ms Delay */
        HAL_Delay(arg_int);
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_CS:
        /* Insert codes for SS pin control */
        //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OLED_CS_GPIO_Port, OLED_CS_Pin, arg_int);
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_DC:
        /* Insert codes for DC pin control */
        //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OLED_DC_GPIO_Port, OLED_DC_Pin, arg_int);
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_GPIO_RESET:
        /* Insert codes for RST pin control */
        //HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OLED_RST_GPIO_Port, OLED_RST_Pin, arg_int);
        break;
    }
    return 1;
}

uint8_t u8x8_byte_stm32_hw_i2c(u8x8_t *u8g2, uint8_t msg, uint8_t arg_int, void *arg_ptr)
{
    /* u8g2/u8x8 will never send more than 32 bytes between START_TRANSFER and END_TRANSFER */
    static uint8_t buffer[32];
    static uint8_t buf_idx;
    static uint8_t dc = 0;
    uint8_t *data;
    switch(msg)
    {
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_SEND:
        data = (uint8_t *)arg_ptr;
        while( arg_int > 0 )
        {
            buffer[buf_idx++] = *data;
            data++;
            arg_int--;
        }
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_INIT:
        /* add your custom code to init i2c subsystem */
        u8g2->gpio_and_delay_cb(&u8g2, U8X8_MSG_DELAY_NANO,u8g2->display_info->post_chip_enable_wait_ns, NULL);
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_SET_DC:
        dc= arg_int;
        //if(HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (DEVICE_ADDRESS << 1), 0x00,1, (uint8_t*) arg_ptr, arg_int,HAL_MAX_DELAY)!= HAL_OK) return 0;
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_START_TRANSFER:
        buf_idx = 0;
        break;
    case U8X8_MSG_BYTE_END_TRANSFER:
        while (HAL_I2C_STATE_READY != HAL_I2C_GetState(&hi2c1)) {
        };
        if(HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&hi2c1, (DEVICE_ADDRESS << 1), buffer, buf_idx, TX_TIMEOUT) != HAL_OK) return 0;
        //if(HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, (DEVICE_ADDRESS << 1),0x40,1, (uint8_t*) arg_ptr, arg_int,HAL_MAX_DELAY)!= HAL_OK) return 0;
        break;

    default:
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

#define  U8G2_H
#ifdef  U8G2_H
static u8g2_t u8g2;
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;
#define width 128
#define height 64
#endif

#ifdef  U8G2_H
    u8g2_Setup_ssd1309_i2c_128x64_noname2_f(&u8g2, U8G2_R0, u8x8_byte_stm32_hw_i2c,u8x8_gpio_and_delay_stm32);  // U8G2_R0 describes the rotation; this mode indicates no rotation, but you can rotate the screen if needed
    //u8x8_d_ssd1309_128x64_noname2(&u8x8, U8X8_R0, u8x8_byte_stm32_hw_i2c,u8x8_gpio_and_delay_stm32);
    u8g2_InitDisplay(&u8g2);
    u8g2_SetPowerSave(&u8g2, 0);
#endif

#ifdef  U8G2_H
    u8g2_FirstPage(&u8g2);
    do {
        u8g2_SetDrawColor(&u8g2,1);
        u8g2_DrawLine(&u8g2, 0, 0, 127, 63);
    } while (u8g2_NextPage(&u8g2));
#endif

My screen shows noises sometimes. It seems like the first pixels of each page are correct (the first 8), but the rest are not.
I have tried modifying the initialization. When using another library, I understand the commands for the screen (e.g., WriteCommand(0xAF) to turn on the display). However, most of the time, some areas of my screen are filled with noise.
If anyone can help, it would be incredible. Thanks!
Edit: A friend of mine made the screen works using another library but most importantly the parameter for the Init,
void OLED_Init()
{
    //unsigned char i;
    writeCommand(0xFD); // Set Command Lock
    writeCommand(0X12); //   Default => 0x12
                        //     0x12 => Driver IC interface is unlocked from entering command.
                        //     0x16 => All Commands are locked except 0xFD.

    writeCommand(0XAE); // Set Display On/Off
                        //   Default => 0xAE
                        //     0xAE => Display Off
                        //     0xAF => Display On

    writeCommand(0xD5); // Set Display Clock Divide Ratio / Oscillator Frequency
    writeCommand(0XA0); // Set Clock as 116 Frames/Sec
                        //   Default => 0x70
                        //     D[3:0] => Display Clock Divider
                        //     D[7:4] => Oscillator Frequency

    writeCommand(0xA8); // Set Multiplex Ratio
    writeCommand(0X3F); //   Default => 0x3F (1/64 Duty)

    writeCommand(0xD3); // Set Display Offset
    writeCommand(0X00); //   Default => 0x00

    writeCommand(0x40); // Set Mapping RAM Display Start Line (0x00~0x3F)
                        //   Default => 0x40 (0x00)

    writeCommand(0xD8); // Set Low Power Display Mode (0x04/0x05)
    writeCommand(0x05); //   Default => 0x04 (Normal Power Mode)

    writeCommand(0x20); // Set Page Addressing Mode (0x00/0x01/0x02)
    writeCommand(0x00); //   Default => 0x02
                        //     0x00 => Horizontal Addressing Mode
                        //     0x01 => Vertical Addressing Mode
                        //     0x02 => Page Addressing Mode

    writeCommand(0xA1); // Set SEG/Column Mapping (0xA0/0xA1)
                        //   Default => 0xA0
                        //     0xA0 => Column Address 0 Mapped to SEG0
                        //     0xA1 => Column Address 0 Mapped to SEG127

    writeCommand(0xC8); // Set COM/Row Scan Direction (0xC0/0xC8)
                        //   Default => 0xC0
                        //     0xC0 => Scan from COM0 to 63
                        //     0xC8 => Scan from COM63 to 0

    writeCommand(0xDA); // Set COM Pins Hardware Configuration
    writeCommand(0x12); //   Default => 0x12
                        //     Alternative COM Pin Configuration
                        //     Disable COM Left/Right Re-Map

    writeCommand(0x81); // Set SEG Output Current
    writeCommand(0x7f); //0x05); // Set Contrast Control for Bank 0
                        //   Default => 0x7F

    writeCommand(0xD9); // Set Pre-Charge as 2 Clocks & Discharge as 5 Clocks
    writeCommand(0x25); //   Default => 0x22 (2 Display Clocks [Phase 2] / 2 Display Clocks [Phase 1])
                        //     D[3:0] => Phase 1 Period in 1~15 Display Clocks
                        //     D[7:4] => Phase 2 Period in 1~15 Display Clocks

    writeCommand(0xDB); // Set VCOMH Deselect Level
    writeCommand(0x34); //   Default => 0x34 (0.78*VCC)

    writeCommand(0xA4); // Set Entire Display On / Off
                        //   Default => 0xA4
                        //     0xA4 => Normal Display
                        //     0xA5 => Entire Display On

    writeCommand(0xA6); // Set Inverse Display On/Off
                        //   Default => 0xA6
                        //     0xA6 => Normal Display
                        //     0xA7 => Inverse Display On

    fillRam(0x00);          // Clear Screen

    writeCommand(0XAF); // Display On (0xAE/0xAF)
}


The initialisation code shows that you are using horizontal addressing and scanning  col from 0 to 127, and row from 63 to 0. Question is 1) is this how your font is defined? 2) so because of this, your U8X8_MSG_BYTE_SEND routine is probably not matching the addressing scheme. So read the SSD1309 datasheet to have better understanding, and maybe try to change the Page Addressing Mode to see is there any difference.
